# How to call environment objects from names in vectors

Tags: r, environment-variables

There are the names of the objects (data_frames) in the specified environment.

```
ls()
[1] "a"         "b"
```

I have assigned the names of the objects to a vector, e.g.
`n_obj <- c('a', 'b')`

How to call my objects using the vector of the names `n_obj`?
`n_obj[1]` return logical a string 'a', but I need to run 'a' as my saved dataframe 'a' in the environment.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the get function

```
get(n_obj[1])
```

Comment: Heuréka! THANKS A LOT! A feel a little stupid :-D

Comment: Also mget(n_obj) get them all as a named list.